# semi parametric Gaussian process derivation

Tags: gaussian-process

I’m reading Murphy’s machine learning book on Gaussian process. It briefly mentions semi parametric Gaussian process, but I have trouble deriving the formulas. It gives a citation to the book Gaussian Process for Machine Learning, page 28, as below:
http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf

My question is how they got the covariance term for the predictive distribution for f*... and especially, where is the matrix R coming from in the cov(f*) term.

Thanks for any help!

Jerome